# What does [+A] mean in Scala class declaration?

Tags: scala, types

In scala Option class is declared like

```
  sealed abstract class _Option[+A]

  case object _None extends _Option[Nothing] {}

  final case class _Some[+A](x: A) extends _Option[A] {}
```

What is `[+A]`? Why not just `[A]`? Could it be `[-A]` and what it would mean?

Sorry if it is a duplicate but I couldn't find the answer on SO.

Comment: Those are variance annotations. As a rule of thumb you should spend some time getting the hang of the language before rushing to SO. The  scala info page on this very site (http://stackoverflow.com/tags/scala/info) has a lot of pointers to learning material. Concerning variance, see by example http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/type-parameterization.html.

Comment: @EndeNeu yes, the content of the question is similar... But you will never find the right answer if you do not know what "covariance" is.

Comment: That's a very good point. Which is why you need to invest some time on some learning material first (even if only by skimming over it).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It declares the class to be *covariant* in its generic parameter.  For your example, it means that `Option[T]` is a subtype of `Option[S]` if `T` is a subtype of `S`.  So, for example, `Option[String]` is a subtype of `Option[Object]`, allowing you to do:

```
val x: Option[String] = Some("a")
val y: Option[Object] = x
```

Conversely, a class can be *contravariant* in its generic parameter if it is declared as `-A`.

Read above variances in Scala in the docs [here](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/variances.html).